# What am i missing: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function onclick

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, undefined

making a simple wp plugin to add 2 buttons right under the login field to populate #user_login and #user_pass on click.

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Change Login Value
* Plugin URI: http://dashboarddemo.mbtdesigns.com
* Description: Change wp-login values
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Matt Taylor
* Author URI: http://Mbtdesigns.com
* License: GPL2
*/


add_action('login_form','login_extra_buttons');

function login_extra_buttons() {

?>  
<a href="#" onclick="$('#user_login').value = 'demo';$('#user_pass').value = 'demo';">Demo Login</a>
<a href="#" onclick="$('#user_login').value = 'admin'; $('#user_pass').value = 'demo';">Admin Login</a>


}
```

I'm getting a undefined error on onclick...what i'm I missing here.. can't seem to spot it..

Comment: You haven't imported jQuery yet, perhaps?

Comment: I'm trying to populate the login form fields with the values that are set in the buttons.

Comment: What is `$` in your code?

Comment: You are missing to understand the error message. You should ask more specifically about your understanding problem of that message.

Comment: Could you please run the following code: `console.log($)` and tell me what it says in your console?

Comment: Undefined, undefined.

Comment: @MBTDesigns then there's a problem with the importing of your libraries. See my answer for a further explanation.

Comment: If it's showing up as `undefined`, then that means it's being declared somehow. You need to provide a full example. There's not enough information to go on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use vanilla javascript instead of jquery here? Just reference the elements by their ids directly:

```
<?php
/**
* Plugin Name: Change Login Value
* Plugin URI: http://dashboarddemo.mbtdesigns.com
* Description: Change wp-login values
* Version: 1.0
* Author: Matt Taylor
* Author URI: http://Mbtdesigns.com
* License: GPL2
*/


add_action('login_form','login_extra_buttons');

function login_extra_buttons() {

?>  
<a href="#" onclick="user_login.value = 'demo'; user_pass.value = 'demo';">Demo Login</a>
<a href="#" onclick="user_login.value = 'admin'; user_pass.value = 'demo';">Admin Login</a>
<?php
}
```

No need to waste jQuery on this IMHO.

Comment: While I like the suggestion to use vanilla, it doesn't specifically address what the question is asking. Either way, I don't think it's a good idea to realy on the implicit global variables like `user_login`. It has spotty browser support.

Comment: @cookiemonster: You are probably right and using `document.getElementById('user_login').value` is more safe and even more vanilla. However, do you have reference which browsers are not supporting referencing DOM elements by their ID?

Comment: Firefox hasn't until recently. I know IE does, but don't remember if all versions of Chrome do, or if they adopted it later. But even aside from browser support, sometimes people run into issues with name conflicts. The variable scope of an inline handler has several objects in it including the element itself and the `document`, and sometimes one can run across the wrong value. However, it does make things a little shorter since you can use `getElementById` without referencing the `document`.

Comment: works... should it be changed to "getElementById('user_login').value = 'demo'; etc.?

Comment: Yes, should be. Or `this.ownerDocument.getElementById('user_login').value = 'string'` etc. The code in the answer is HTML 5 bound, the code in this comment should work back in older browsers (often preferred).

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be that, whatever library you're using to occupy `$`, is not properly imported, or it is not defining `$` properly. The error is saying you're trying to execute a function of an undefined variable, and in the case of your `onclick` event handler, you're only running the `$` function, so that must be the problem.

This minimal example recreates your code:

```
var example;
example('#user_login').value; //results in TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

So, if you're trying to use jQuery, you'll need to include an import of jQuery. You can see http://jquery.com for instructions.

Comment: Is it jQuery? If so, and it isn't imported then `$` would be undeclared, then the error message would be different. It would be *"ReferenceError: $ is not defined"* instead.

Comment: @cookiemonster There's no other way this can be explained, unless there is another piece of code that's not provided by the asker. See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23858247/1256925#comment36720008_23858247) for confirmation that my answer is indeed correct in assuming `$`  is undefined.

Comment: The code in the question looks pretty messed up. I voted to close it as off topic: not enough info... Hate to say it, but this one just feels like a waste of time.

Comment: Well, the problem is already clear: `$ === undefined` in OP's situation (based on [the comment I linked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23858247/1256925#comment36720008_23858247)). So, the solution is importing jQuery (or whatever library he needs).

Comment: Yupp, this is the answer. Removing mine.

Comment: If it's `undefined`, then that means it's declared. So the question is why is it declared without a value? Maybe jQuery is imported but the `$` is overwritten. Maybe he defined `$` as an IIFE function parameter, but didn't pass anything to it. If it was as simple as a failure to import, then it would be a *ReferenceError*.

Comment: May be, worth trying to use full `jQuery` insetead of `$`

Comment: @cookiemonster well, that's true. I guess you're right. Based on the provided code, there's indeed nothing further that can be determined to find the actual source of the problem. All we can do is guess.

Comment: @Joeytje50: Yep, and I don't use PHP, so I don't know if it's normal, but seeing an opening PHP tag, followed by a comment and a function call, followed by the start of a function declaration, followed by the closing PHP tag (I think), followed by HTML, followed the closing of the function declaration just doesn't seem right.

Comment: ...could also be variable hoisting for the `add_action()` call, where it's defined later, but not with `var` syntax instead of function declaration syntax.

Comment: @cookiemonster it is possible in PHP to do stuff like `<?php if ($somevar > 10) { ?> <div>yup</div> <?php } ?>`, but in this case, I'm also not sure what that would do.

Comment: @cookiemonster no, because that `add_action()` function is ran within PHP, and OP already said that `$ === undefined` in his comment.

Comment: Ah right. It is the `$` then. Something is messed up somewhere. I just wonder if it's a misapplication of an IIFE, like `(function($) { ... })();` instead of `(function($) { ... })(jQuery);` Anyway, he really need to provide a full working example.